# Can't Concatenate String in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am just trying to concatenate a string on to a column returned from the database like so:

```
var aaData = 
    (from pr in ctx.PaymentRates
        where pr.ServiceRateCodeId == new Guid("BBCE42CB-56E3-4848-B396-4656CCE3CE96")
        select new
        {
            Id = pr.Id,
            Rate = pr.YearOneRate + "helloWorld"
        })
        .ToList();
```

It gives me this error:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'.
>   LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration
>   types.

So, then I tried this:

```
var aaData = 
    (from pr in ctx.PaymentRates
        where pr.ServiceRateCodeId == new Guid("BBCE42CB-56E3-4848-B396-4656CCE3CE96")
        select new
        {
            pr = pr
        })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.pr.Id,
            Rate = x.pr.YearOneRate + "helloWorld"
        })
        .ToList();
```

But, now it gives me this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

On this line:

```
.Select(x => new
```

How can I concatenate these strings in LINQ?

Comment: What's the type of YearOneRate? It sounds like it contains NULL values. Try something like: Rate = (pr.YearOneRate ?? "") + "helloWorld"

Comment: Are you sure that `homeC` and `hostC` are effective. If not you will get a nullpointer (what is basically what goes wrong here). On what line the error appears?

Comment: @Magus "You can't concatenate a string to something that isn't a string" - sure you can.  The other thing will be implicitly converted via `object.ToString()`.

Comment: @Magus You can concat a string to *anything*, even if it's not a string.  If you couldn't, then your change wouldn't work either.

Comment: `pr.YearOneRate` is a double.  So, I've tried `Rate = (pr.YearOneRate ?? 0).ToString() + "helloWorld"` however, it says, "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Now that you have removed the left joins, your second example using `.AsEnumerable()` should have worked, and your own answer backs that up because it is essentially the same (although still flawed) with the left joins fixed as suggested by several answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, I wasn't using `.AsEnumerable()` properly.  The code below works:

```
var aaData = 
    (from pr in ctx.PaymentRates
        from homeC in ctx.Countries.Where(x => x.Id == pr.HomeCountryId).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from hostC in ctx.Countries.Where(x => x.Id == pr.HostCountryId).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from curr in ctx.Currencies.Where(x => x.Id == pr.YearOneCurrencyId).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where pr.ServiceRateCodeId.Value.Equals(new Guid("BBCE42CB-56E3-4848-B396-4656CCE3CE96"))
        select new { pr, homeC, hostC, curr })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Id = (string)(x.pr.Id.ToString() + "test"),
            HomeCountry = (x.homeC != null ? x.homeC.Name : ""),
            HostCountry = (x.hostC != null ? x.hostC.Name : ""),
            Rate = (x.pr.YearOneRate ?? 0) + " (" + x.curr.Code + ")"
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: You were using `AsEnumerable` properly in your edited question. The difference is that you have now fixed most of the left joins. But now you could get a null reference in the call to `x.Curr.Code` because that is a new left join. You can also use `SqlFunctions` to convert nullable doubles to strings in linq-to-entities. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

**The quick solution**

Regarding your second code chunk I need to point out to you that you're actually doing two left outer joins on the `Countries` table/set, one for `homeC` and one for `hostC`.

That means that you are willing to accept `null` values for those two variables.
In other words, since they **can** be `null` you are somehow allowing this right here to crash with `NullReferenceException`, should those variables turn out to be `null`:

```
.Select(x => new
    {
        Id = x.pr.Id,
        HomeCountry = x.homeC.Name,
        HostCountry = x.hostC.Name,
        Rate = x.pr.YearOneRate + "helloWorld"
    })
```

The error (`NullReferenceException` or as you saw it's message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") is not here

`.Select(x =>`

but rather here

`x.homeC.Name` and `x.hostC.Name`

where you will most certainly dereference a `null` reference.

That's just Visual Studio's way of pointing out the best statement that fits around the error.

So, the quickest solution would be to do this:

```
.Select(x => new
    {
        Id = x.pr.Id,
        HomeCountry = (x.homeC != null) ? x.homeC.Name : "HomeCountry not found",
        HostCountry = (x.hostC.Name != null) ? x.hostC.Name : "HostCountry not found",
        Rate = x.pr.YearOneRate + "helloWorld"
    })
```

Notice the modification which ensures that you will still be able to extract *some* information from result set records for which `homeC` and `hostC` are `null`.

**EDIT**

Regarding the first query you posted:

```
var aaData = 
(from pr in ctx.PaymentRates
    where pr.ServiceRateCodeId == new Guid("BBCE42CB-56E3-4848-B396-4656CCE3CE96")
    select new
    {
        Id = pr.Id,
        Rate = pr.YearOneRate + "helloWorld"
    })
    .ToList();
```

my guess is that your 'YearOnRate' property is of type 'Nullable< of something >" (maybe `decimal` -- so for instance it is maybe a `decimal? YearOnRate { get; set; }`) and the corresponding column in the database *is a nullable one*.

If that is the case, then I think (in this first version of your endeavour) you could try to do this:

```
Rate = (pr.YearOnRate != null) ? pr.YearOneRate.Value + "helloWorld" : "[null]helloWorld"
```

and get away with it.

Comment: Sorry, I should've simplified the code. I removed the `homeC` and `hostC` stuff but I still get the errors.  The problem probably isn't related to that.

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives me this error: `Unable to cast the type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.`

Comment: Nevermind, I found my answer (posted here).  Thanks.

Comment: Hello there: Posted where ? I would like to ask you to stop asking question which aren't defined as much as possible by you, the asker. You did not explain what the types of the properties of your entities are (I only presumed the type of YearOnRate would be decimal because it sounded like a financial value but that was merely guessing... Turns out I was right). I admit that I wasn't aware of the fact that in EF you can't orchestrate the RDBMS to convert a decimal value to string in order to concatenate it to another string through a LINQ query.

Comment: Furthermore, this should be a place where blocking situations and blocking questions get solved by the community, in one way or the other. But if you're not a new user you should already be aware of the fact that you shouldn't ask for highly specific issues which are only part of your particular scenario **and** mindset. You should try to generalise the state you're in as much as possible before posting a question. If you're question is vague and you receive _at least_ some form of boost in the right direction which you didn't rigorously define anyway, from answers, you should be thankful

Comment: ... and you can't say, "nevermind" and then be sloppy about some URL which didn't get pasted in. If this is really a "never mind" kind of situation, then please delete your own question since it and its answers are hopeless and are only making the haystack bigger, for those who are looking for a resolution to their personal blackings issues (the needle). Don't forget, the role of StackOverflow is not just to get your own issue solved but also to make this unpleasant experience available to others that might also find themselves in a similar situation. This right here is just more haystack.

Comment: You are clearly having a bad day and taking it out on me! Sorry to have stumbled upon you at an inconvenient time. My answer is posted on this very page http://stackoverflow.com/a/21413536/1477388.  Lastly, I am very thankful; however, none of the answers provided solved the actual problem. The problem was, I needed to use `.AsEnumerable()` differently than I was using it before. This is something that a future user may need to know.

Comment: I'm sorry for not noticing that right here was really here here :). Sorry 'bout that. But still, you haven't explained anything to a potential reader who might be experiencing the same thing. You're not using .AsEnumerable() differently, it's exactly the same. You've changed on the other hand things which were originally in your question, I and all the other guys explained you had to change to make it better ( the (homeC ==null) ? null : homeC.Name stuff ), you said it was overly complicated and deleted that part from the question, now in your own answer you're actually using those things etc

Comment: The other stuff isn't a factor in the problem or solution; I guess I just added it for completeness. The only thing I really changed was the `select new { }` stuff. Not sure why it makes a difference - but it works.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that either `x.homeC`, `x.hostC`, or `x.pr` are null.  If you're fine using `AsEnumerable` to convert to Linq-to-Objects then you could just change your projection to

```
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Id = (x.pr.HasValue ? x.pr.Id : 0),
        HomeCountry = (x.homeC.HasValue ? x.homeC.Name : null),
        HostCountry = (x.hostC.HasValue ? x.hostC.Name : null),
        Rate = (x.pr.HasValue ? x.pr.YearOneRate : null) + "helloWorld"
    })
```

Comment: I tried your code as `Rate = (pr.YearOneRate.HasValue ? pr.YearOneRate : null) + "helloWorld"` but I got this error `Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.`

Answer (score 0):

You have used `DefaultIfEmpty` on both `homeC` and `hostC` so you can get a null reference when you call `homeC.Name` or `hostC.Name`

Try using `HomeCountry = homeC == null ? null : homeC.Name` instead

If `pr.YearOneRate` is not a string and you want the concatenation done by the database engine you need to tell Linq-to-Entities to generate sql to convert it. If you are using Sql Server you can use this:

`SqlFunctions.StringConvert(pr.YearOneRate) + "helloWorld"`

If you don't need the concatenation done in the database then you can use `AsEnumerable()` before the Select so that you are running Linq-To-Objects

Comment: Sorry, I should've simplified the code. I removed the `homeC` and `hostC` stuff but I still get the errors.  The problem probably isn't related to that.